# thought experiment concerning $E = m\cdot c^2$

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, mass-energy

### Setup:

Suppose one has two identical wheels $W_1$ and $W_2$. Wheel $W_1$ is rotating about its axis with angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ while the other wheel is not rotating. Imagine then two identical carts $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the rotating wheel $W_1$ inside $C_1$ and the non-rotating wheel $W_2$ inside the cart $C_2$. Initially the velocity of both carts is $\vec{v}_1 = \vec{v_2} = \begin{bmatrix}0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}^T$.

### Question:

Suppose that to both carts $C_1$ and $C_2$ is applied the same constant force $\vec{F}$ for $1$ second. After $1$ second is the velocity of cart $C_1$ slightly smaller then the velocity of cart $C_2$?

### Answer (...)

This is a question that I formed to test some understanding about relativity. I think the wheel $W_1$ has a greater energy then the wheel $W_2$ hence it has a slightly greater inertial mass, therefore the final velocity of cart $C_1$ should be smaller then the velocity of cart $C_2$! Is this correct?

I have never worked seriously with relativity, but if I take the notorious formula $E = m\cdot c^2$ and consider $E_1 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot I\cdot \omega^2 > 0 = E_2$ follows that the first wheel has the total energy $E_{1t} = m\cdot c^2 + E_1$ before the cart was moving while and the second wheel has the total energy $E_{2t} = m\cdot c^2$. When the the force is applied to the first cart, it tries to move a mass $m_1 = m + \frac{E_1}{c^2} > m$ hence cart $C_1$ should have a smaller acceleration. 
PS:
The second cart will gradually increase its translational energy hence its mass should also be increased, but assume the rotational energy of the former is much greater ... Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a rotating object have more inertia, mass and gravitational pull?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207212)

Comment: Ok, so that is a reason to down vote my question?

Comment: -1 Insufficient research effort. There are many websites (and questions on here) which explain what $E=mc^2$ means.

Comment: I am not always asking questions to learn something but rather to confirm that what I've learned is right, as is the case here. Is this behavior  discouraged?

Comment: see also [Does a spinning object acquire mass due to its rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/289470)

Comment: Questions which only ask for Yes/No answers are discouraged. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/self-study-students-confirmation-type-questions/6672#6672

Comment: So ... the questions and answers you've suggested are an year apart. Have you down voted the later?

Comment: Ok, ok about that part about yes or no, thou! Thank you very much for the proposed questions :) Ok, I might give you another question to down vote, but can you have a look at this [other question of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390243/a-conceptual-propulsion-device-based-on-instantaneous-energy-transfer) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a rotating object have more inertia, mass and gravitational pull?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207212/does-a-rotating-object-have-more-inertia-mass-and-gravitational-pull)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Energy increases inertia. Of course, in typical situations $E_1/c^2$ is much much smaller than the masses, which is why this effect was discovered theoretically and not experimentally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is also true if, for instance, instead of wheels one would consider, say, capacitors or inductors ?! That means that a charged capacitor has a slightly greater inertial mass that the one who is not charged ...

Comment: Can you sir have a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390243/a-conceptual-propulsion-device-based-on-instantaneous-energy-transfer) question?